# RubyMine: Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am using RubyMine 8. After I created a new project I tried to look at the rails version by typing `$ rails -v`, then I got `Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.` I tried to install rake by typing `$ gem install rake` but I still get this error. Can someone help me? Here are two screenshots: [Cannot find rake error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOvNm.png)  and  [Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgjG6.png).

I tried bundle install and bundle update by going into Tools-->Bundler-->Install(and Update), and I've checked rake version by typing `rake --version`(gives me 10.5.0) but neither of them works. Thank you!!

Comment: what version of rake are running on the project? try rake --version inside you project folder.

Comment: have you tried `bundle update`?

Comment: I've tried both advice from comments but they don't work, I updated my question with two screenshots. Please see if you could help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by

1. Uninstall ALL gems, including rails gem:
   `gem uninstall -aIx`
2. Re-install rails:
   `gem install rails`
3. Then RubyMine somehow don't detect the rails version I just installed, to create a project, run 
   `rails new projectName`
   in the terminal to create a project, and then open the project folder in RubyMine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
Bundle exec rake rake-command
```

And use

```
rails -version
```

To know the rails version
After all this run

```
bundle install
```

..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. The problem is whatever I do, I can't run rails -v. I added rake to my Gemfile and run bundle install, rake even appears in the list of the gems installed and has a directory, but whenever I run rails -v, I get the "cannot find rake" message and get a warning message in the screenshot.